# jQuery Datatables: Using a database object

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am populating the fields of my User object in a datatable.  The User object has a database field for `email` and `phone` , so that works as expected.  The `name` field is actually an object with a bunch of keys in it so I want to use `first_name`.  I tried doing the below but it doesn't seem to work. If I use just `name`, it renders out `[Object object]` so I know it's accessing `name` correctly.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    data: [
        'email,
        'phone',
        'name['first_name']'
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data, you could reference it by using `name.first_name`.